# Will $product->save() trigger catalog_product_save_after?

Tags: module, event-observer

I have an module A will save a product using

```
$product->save();
```

This module will run in cron job.

And another module B has

```
<catalog_product_save_after>
   <observers>
      <warehouse_save_product_batch_special_prices>
        <class>warehouse/catalog_product_price_observer</class>
        <method>saveBatchSpecialPrices</method>
      </warehouse_save_product_batch_special_prices>
   </observers>
</catalog_product_save_after>
```

Anyone know module A will or will not trigger module B function?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, definitely, if you check the `save` function of `Mage_Core_Model_Abstract` you can see this:

```
public function save()
{
    /**
     * Direct deleted items to delete method
     */
    if ($this->isDeleted()) {
        return $this->delete();
    }
    if (!$this->_hasModelChanged()) {
        return $this;
    }
    $this->_getResource()->beginTransaction();
    $dataCommited = false;
    try {
        $this->_beforeSave();
        if ($this->_dataSaveAllowed) {
            $this->_getResource()->save($this);
            $this->_afterSave();
        }
        $this->_getResource()->addCommitCallback(array($this, 'afterCommitCallback'))
            ->commit();
        $this->_hasDataChanges = false;
        $dataCommited = true;
    } catch (Exception $e) {
        $this->_getResource()->rollBack();
        $this->_hasDataChanges = true;
        throw $e;
    }
    if ($dataCommited) {
        $this->_afterSaveCommit();
    }
    return $this;
}
```

This line: `$this->_beforeSave();` triggers the following events:

- `model_save_before`
- `$this->_eventPrefix.'_save_before'` where the event prefix depends on your model. In your case, it is `catalog_product`

On the other hand, this line: `$this->_afterSave()` triggers the following events:

- `model_save_after`
- `$this->_eventPrefix.'_save_after'` (same remark as before)